# IE Problem - jQuery append inside a table tag for each Ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am appending some html inside a table tag while performing each Ajax request.I need to show the appended html immediatly after performing the ajax request.
It is working fine in FF, but in IE it shows the appended html only after completing all the ajax requests.

Following is the code

```
while(cond)

{

$.ajax({
                // other codes    
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#tblPOUpdateResult tr:last').after(GetHtmlFromProblems(data));
                }
            });
}

function GetHtmlFromProblems(data) {

    var output = "";
    output = "<tr><td>" + data.PurchaseOrderNumber + "</td><td>";

    if (data.Result.WasSuccessful == true) {
        output = output + "<div style='color: green'> Sucess </div></td><td>";
    }
    else {
        output = output + "<div style='color: red'>Failed</div></td><td>";    
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.PurchaseOrderNotFound == true) {
        output = output + "Purchase order was not found";
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.NoChangesToSave == true) {
        output = output + "There is no change to update <br />";
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.PurchaseOrderIsForADifferentVendor == true) {
        output = output + "Purchase Order belongs to a different vendor <br />";
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.PurchaseOrderIsNotDirectShip == true) {
        output = output + "Purchase Order is not Direct ShipSet <br />";
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.LineIsNotForSpecifiedPart == true) {
        output = output + "Purchase Order Line is specified for different part <br />";
    }

    if (data.Result.Problems.QuantityReceivedExceedsQuantityOrdered == true) {
        output = output + "Quantity received exceeded quanity ordered <br />";
    }

    if (data.Result.HasAnyProblem == false) {
        output = output + "There is no problem<br />";
    }
    output = output + "</td></tr>";

    return output;
}
```

Html Page:

```
<div id="PurchaseOrderUpdateResults">
                    <table cellspacing='0' class='grid_table bordered no_table_padding no_wrap_table' id="tblPOUpdateResult">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Purchase Order Number
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Problems
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated :) I m using IE 7.

Comment: Have you tried `append()` rather than `after()` just to test it out?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one too... See below

$('#tblPOUpdateResult > tbody').append(data)

Comment: Try putting `sleep(100)` at the end of the while loop to give it a chance to execute before the next iteration is called.

Comment: sleep(100)... Is this a method of jQuery?

Comment: No.... True.  There is a `delay` method though.  Can you show all your code?

Comment: maybe its because you making too many ajax requests and the way ie deals with ajax requests. another thing is that tables do not render until the the end table tab `</table>`. use the queue so you dont bombard ie with too many requests as ie is too slow lol :)

Comment: "Nick, I have updated the Question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself.

The reason why append was not working was my jQuery ajax request was synchronous. i.e) I had set the async :false property in ajax function.

Once I removed the async property. It worked properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the table-layout property as given here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531161%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

> You can optimize table rendering
>   performance by specifying the
>   tableLayout property. This property
>   causes Windows Internet Explorer to
>   render the table one row at a time,
>   providing users with information at a
>   faster pace.

HTH

Comment: We use table sorter plugin and we face the same problem...loads in less than 2 sec in FF but takes 11 secs in IE (1.5 sec for the server request and rest for rendering)....If you are not gonna act upon the table I highly suggest using divs...HTH